# I want to filter item count added by supplier for each month in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am new to MongoDB and I want to get the item count added by the handicraftmen for each of the months.

As an example January = 10, February =15 .... like that.

This is my model

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const handicraftmen = require('../models/handicraftmen')

const item_model =new mongoose.Schema({
    handicraftmen_id:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: handicraftmen,
        require: true,
    },
    category: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        require: true,
    },
    stock: {
        type: Number,
        require: true,
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
    },
},{timestamps: true});

const item = mongoose.model('Item',item_model);
module.exports=item;
```

and this is my one item in item list.

```
_id:62f5df71dabf3cd385c6beee
handicraftmen_id:62f251c28ce1837d3f275908
category:"Masks"
name:"wooden mask"
price:500
stock:8
description:"Wooden mask"
createdAt:2022-08-12T05:04:49.502+00:00
updatedAt:2022-09-02T16:23:14.885+00:00
```

there are a lot of items in the list added by different handicraftmens in different months.
I want to get specific handicraftmen items and filter those into months and get item count for each month.

how did I get that using a mongoose query?

Answer (score 0):

You can write an aggregation pipeline for this.

1. Use `$match` to filter documents matching handicraftmen.
2. Add a new field `date` which is basically a breakdown of `createdAt`, into various time components. Using `$addFields` and `$dateToParts`.
3. Use `$group` to get counts for each month.
4. Convert the numeric month index to string value using `$addFields` again, and remove `_id` using `$project`.

Like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      handicraftmen_id: "62f251c28ce1837d3f275908"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "date": {
        "$dateToParts": {
          "date": {
            "$toDate": "$createdAt"
          },
          
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$date.month",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "month": {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          [
            "",
            "January",
            "February",
            "March",
            "April",
            "May",
            "June",
            "July",
            "August",
            "September",
            "October",
            "November",
            "December"
          ],
          "$_id"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

This is the playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lIfGcQcpckp). You can use the mongoose [aggregate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate) method, similarly.